# Table not Shifted up at the time of new Cell insertion in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, xcode

I insert new cell in my table using insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: method on button click of particular cell. but i face one problem while i click on the last cell of table at that time table not shifted up. i try scrollview but still i am not get resolve problem. i want that when i click last cell at that time table shifted up for particular inserted cell height. please provide me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your edits to the UITableView are inside begin/end updates. The changes don't appear until you call end. Make sure that by the time you call endUpdates that the new data is reflected in the table's data source. eg.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
// ... inserts and deletes
[tableView endUpdates];
```